# Horizontal Line Not getting any border-style

Tags: html, css

I tried to use `border-style: dotted;`
but the horizontal line which was supposed to be dotted doesn't get dotted. tried googling it .. didn't help

[image]

Comment: Please don't add screenshots of your code but show us the actual code instead.

Comment: What I can see is that you have not added `border-width` and `border-color` to your code. Normally you can set the same with `border: 2px dotted red` shorthand.

Comment: @Behemoth by actual code is it that the proof (website) is not necessary?

Comment: No dont worry but its a lot more comfortable if people can take a look at the code in text form --> allows to copy, paste and play around with the  code more easily.

Comment: @Behemoth Oh I'm Sorry I am particularly new here so I forgot . I will keep that in my mind next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, let me clear you one thing this is not how the horizontal lines are created usually to make a horizontal line you want to do something like this with your `<hr>`,

```css
hr {
border: none;                      /** <- Note this line */
border-top: 1px dotted purple;       /** <- And then this line */
color: purple;
background-color: purple;
height: 1px;
width: 100%;                       /** You can set it to any length as per your need. */            
}
```

Comment: @AronnyaRifat usually to create a separator either set the `top` or the `bottom` border of the element you want to make a separator of.

Answer (score 1):

The [`<hr/>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/hr) shows as one continuous line because you added a [`background-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/background-color). You have to use [`border-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/border-color) instead and add a [`border-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/border-width).

```css
hr {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: dotted;
  border-color: purple;
  /* background-color: purple; <-- remove this line */
}
```

```html
<hr/>
```

Or just use the shorthand.
For instance:

```css
hr {
  border: 2px dotted purple;
}
```

```html
<hr/>
```

You can find more information [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_style_hr.asp).

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
hr {
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
```

it's the same as

```
hr {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: dotted;
  border-color: red;
}
```

```css
hr {
      border: 1px dotted red;
    }
```

```html
<div>
  This is a test
<hr />
  Try it !
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to have one dotted line you should reset border and add only top or bottom border:

```css
hr {
  border: 0;
  border-top: 5px dotted navy;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<hr>
```